# how to make jumbotron 100% height when you have a fixed navbar and body padding-top?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using bootstrap with a modified fixed-navigation bar and a body padding-top of say 113px, I notice that my next snippet the jumbotron covers the width which is perfect for me but I have empty space underneath. I would like to have it cover 100% height of the remaining space and be responsive depending on device you are viewing on. Can this be done?

So far the closest I have been was 100vh but that seems to fill the space and not take into account the body padding-top 113px so it carries on for what seems to be 113px when you scroll down.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Tom welcome to SO, in order for people to help you and understand your problems, at least provide some code to debug.... please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't answer to your question exactly without seeing the code or at least seeing a screenshot. I think you need to add more 113px to your height.

That can be done by using calc, But if you did this in correct way you shouldn't need this.

```
height: calc(100% + 113px);
```

Complete code

```
html, body {
  /* Make the body to be as tall as browser window */
  height: 100%;
}

.jumbotron {
    height: calc(100% + 113px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I had no idea that  calc() existed and has solved my issue perfectly.

Comment: Although I had to use height: calc(100vh + 113px); and now I have the issue of the jumbotron background image staying the vh from the smaller screen so when expanding the screen it doesnt cover the Div.... I will try upload some code after I have played around with it.